# Mysql find records with double letters in them

Tags: mysql, regex

Guys I need a query which list me all those records in which there are at least 2 of the same letter. Unfortunately

```
"REGEXP  '[a]|[b]|[c]|[d]|[e]|[f]|[g]|[h]|[i]|[j]|[k]|[l]|[m]|[n]|[o]|[p]|[q]|[r]|[s]|[t]|[u]|[v]|[w]|[x]|[y]|[z]';"
```

this one does not work for me, neither the same expession with `[a]{2}` attributes.

Any suggestions?
Thanks for the help

Comment: To clarify: two of the same character side-by-side? Or two of the same character anywhere in the whole record?

And is it expected that two of the same character side-by-side will never occur in a record?

Comment: two of the same character anywhere in the a whole record and it is not expected to be side by side

Comment: So far as I can tell, this isn't something you can do in MySQL, which only has a very simplistic regex engine. You'll have to pass your record into the programming language of your choice, and use this regex: `(.).*(\1)`

Comment: actualy I am not looking to solve this whit regex, I am looking for any kind of sollution whitch is good here (if it is possibly in Mysql) but PHP would be as good as MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT some_fields FROM some_table WHERE field REGEXP
'a{2}|b{2}|c{2}|d{2}|e{2}|f{2}|g{2}|h{2}|i{2}|j{2}|k{2}|l{2}|m{2}|n{2}|o{2}|p{2}|q{2}|r{2}|s{2}|t{2}|u{2}|v{2}|w{2}|x{2}|y{2}|z{2}';
```

It will return all the records in `some_table` whose `field` contains two identical characters side-by-side.

Examples of what it could return (based on one of my local MySQL tables):
hobbit
Abba
Isaac
scrabble

In case the characters don't have to be together, you may use this other query:

```
SELECT some_fields FROM some_table WHERE field REGEXP
'a.*a|b.*b|c.*c|d.*d|e.*e|f.*f|g.*g|h.*h|i.*i|j.*j|k.*k|l.*l|m.*m|n.*n|o.*o|p.*p|q.*q|r.*r|s.*s|t.*t|u.*u|v.*v|w.*w|x.*x|y.*y|z.*z';
```

Examples of what it could return (based on one of my local MySQL tables):
probably  (double B)
curious  (double U)
contrary  (double R)
Abba (double A and double B)

Documentation: [MySQL pattern matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: Unfortunately this one does not give me back all the records that I need, because the 2 letter might not be side by side

Comment: @Stonesmit the second query I just added may be what you need.

Comment: yes the seconc one solved my problem. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has no backreferences, so you might have to use this:

```
REGEXP  'a{2}|b{2}|c{2}|d{2}|e{2}|f{2}|g{2}|h{2}|i{2}|j{2}|k{2}|l{2}|m{2}|n{2}|o{2}|p{2}|q{2}|r{2}|s{2}|t{2}|u{2}|v{2}|w{2}|x{2}|y{2}|z{2}'
```

Comment: Unfortunately this one does not give me back all the records that I need, because the 2 letter might not be side by side

Comment: Use the suggestion from @jocelyn above.